# Keep DataTable but repaginate after repopulating

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am using the DataTable plugin (http://datatables.net) to great effect on a project I am working on but we need it to do what it does plus several more things. On certain actions we need to keep the DataTable right where it is but empty its data rows (the ones in the TBODY) and put new rows in. Now, this part is actually working but once it plugs in all the new rows it shows *all* of those rows and doesn't then break them into pages. Is there a way to then just call the paginating action?

Here's a JS Fiddle-type example: http://live.datatables.net/itaven/7/edit

Am likewise wondering if there's a way to invoke re-sorting (apart from the native ability to sort by clicking on table headers) and to trigger going to a different page of the DataTable by a jQuery action.